# What is the uncertainty on 50 Hz a.c.?

Tags: electricity, frequency, error-analysis, electrical-engineering

We are doing an experiment to measure velocity using the ticker-tape timer which runs on a 50 Hz a.c. 12 V power supply. I am in Ireland. So the time interval between each pair of dots is 0.02 s. But is there an uncertainty on this number ? Surely it's not exactly 0.02. I can't seem to find info on this anywhere online.

Comment: suggest you post this on the [electronics.se]. Lots of experts on AC power over there.

Comment: This is an example of a (possible) systematic error i.e. you have no way of knowing whether the tape is running fast or slow. In general systematic errors are hard to estimate.

Comment: Have a look at the article [Accuracy and stability of the 50 Hz mains frequency](http://wwwhome.cs.utwente.nl/~ptdeboer/misc/mains.html).